# Derivation of expectation maximization algorithm

Tags: probability, expectation

I am reading tutorial on expectation maximization algorithm (http://ai.stanford.edu/~chuongdo/papers/em_tutorial.pdf), I am having trouble understanding second step, Can someone derive the expression?

I have already read( [how does expectation maximization work?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25111/how-does-expectation-maximization-work/860893#comment3465687_860893) ) question, In second answer does P(H9T1) represents probability of getting 9 heads and 1 tail in unbiased coin?